# Spaces in string in <input type="text"> django templates

Tags: django, templates, text, input, spaces

I have this code in a Django Template:

```
input  type="text" name="ppoisNomePOI"  value={{ request.session.ppoisNomePOI }}
```

If my "request.session.ppoisNomePOI" is "John" then in the page it appears "John" in the input,  but if my "request.session.ppoisNomePOI" is "John Flanders Simpson" it only appears "John"

I assume it was a problem with the spaces in the value.

Answer (score 6):

From the sounds of it, the browser is probably treating the subsequent words as empty attributes and being interpreted as:

```
<input type="text" name="ppoisNomePOI" value="John" Flanders Simpson>
```

Try putting quotes around the value.

```
value="{{ request.session.ppoisNomePOI }}"
```

This will force it to be interpreted as:

```
<input type="text" name="ppoisNomePOI" value="John Flanders Simpson">
```

Comment: This worked for me, You saved a lot of headache. Love you man